# C++ Variable keeps resetting to 0

Tags: c++, variables

So I've got this simple piece of code.  What it's supposed to do is calculate centigrade from Fahrenheit.  For some reason, however, it keeps resetting the value of cent to 0.  Can anyone please explain why it's doing this?  I'm sure I'm just missing something small and stupid.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
ofstream fout("temps.dat");
float fahr=0, avgcent=0, avgfahr=0, totalcent=0, totalfahr=0, gettemp=0;
double cent = ((5/9) * (fahr - 32));
const int gatekeeper=-99999;
fout << setw(25) << "Fahrenheit" << setw(20) << "Centigrade" << endl << endl;
fout.setf(ios :: fixed);
fout.setf(ios :: showpoint); 
cout << "Please input Fahrenheit temp (-99999 to quit)" << endl;
cin >> fahr;
while (fahr != gatekeeper)
{

    totalfahr = totalfahr + fahr;
    totalcent = cent + totalcent;
    cout << cent;
    cin >> fahr;

}//End of while (gettemp != gatekeeper)
}//End of int main (void) for HW2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your line `double cent = ((5/9) * (fahr - 32));`, the expression `(5/9)` resolves to `0` because it uses integer division.  Replace it with `(5.0/9.0)` and you should get the correct result.

Comment: -Slams face against table- Omg I knew that...  Thank you for the quick and elegant response that worked perfectly

Comment: @Skathix you could also print out the value of the variable at each line to find out which line was the culprit, or else do the equivalent in a debugging tool such as gdb.

Comment: I was actually doing that @La-comadreja, I need to learn to debug a bit better but what turned me onto the problem was the debugger showing a proper value on the line where it does the division then resetting to 0 on the next line.

Comment: @Skathix - of course, but even trivial debugging is beyond most posters:(